# Why Symfony generate 2 routes when I use annotation routing type and subdirectory?

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony4

I use symfony 4 and the annotation type for routes.
I have an `Admin` directory in my `Controller` directory.
In the `Controller` directory, I have 3 controllers with some routes
And in my `Admin` directory, I have `EmployeeController` (prefixed by "/employee" and named by "employee_") with 3 routes (index, new, edit)

My `annotations.yaml` file look like this:

```
admin:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/Admin/
    type: annotation
    prefix: /admin
    name_prefix: admin_
    trailing_slash_on_root: false

public:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
    trailing_slash_on_root: false
```

After a `bin/console debug:router` I have :

```
admin_employee_index       GET        ANY      ANY    /admin/employee/                   
admin_employee_new         GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /admin/employee/new                
admin_employee_edit        GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /admin/employee/{id}/edit          
employee_index             GET        ANY      ANY    /employee/                         
employee_new               GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /employee/new                      
employee_edit              GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /employee/{id}/edit                
dashboard_index            GET        ANY      ANY    /dashboard/{year}/{week}           
schedule_index             ANY        ANY      ANY    /schedule/{year}/{week}            
localization_index              ANY        ANY      ANY    /localization/{id}
```

It's possible to exclude a controller or a directory that are already configured ?
Because symfony generate 2 routes for the same controller.

Of course I can use a single config for routing (public in this example) and set prefix for admin controller with "/admin/employee" but I don't like this method.  That's mean that every controller need this config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot exclude a directory from routing definition. As a better way of separating controllers you could create `AdminController` directory in `src` and move all admin controllers there.

Comment: Or create a `Public` directory in `Controller` alongside `Admin` so it's still under the controller namespace

Comment: Well, you can create `Public` directory, but it wouldn't work because `Public` is a reserved keyword and cannot be used in namespace.

Comment: Ah true! Caught me out with an entity that should have been `Case` recently but ended up `SupportCase`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  
I think that I will use `AdminController` directory.